# Jsoup connect(): bypass google captcha

Tags: java, jsoup

I make a small application and I have to retrieve the URL based on keywords.
This is the code:

```
  Elements doc = Jsoup
        .connect(request)
        .userAgent(
          "Mozilla 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)")
        .timeout(5000).get().select("li.g>h3>a");


        for (Element link : doc) {

              String url = link.absUrl("href"); 
            try {
              url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
            }



            if(!url.startsWith("http")) 
                continue; // Ads/news/etc.
            else if(url.contains("/pdf/"))
                continue;
            else if(url.contains("//github.com/"))
                continue;


            res.add(url);
        }
```

just get the following error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://www.google.com/search%3Flr%3Dlang_en....
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:446)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
at sperimentazioni.Main.getDataFromGoogle(Main.java:327)
at sperimentazioni.Main.getURLs(Main.java:164)
at sperimentazioni.Main.main(Main.java:485)
```

Apparently it is the captcha google, how can I bypass?

Comment: This is why Captchas exist. To stop non-humans like your code. I don't think anyone is going to help you get around it...

Comment: it is possible to use another search engine? if so, which one?

Comment: I am guessing all would do this to a certain extent. Although scraping probably isn't the way to go for this.You'll want to use their official API. Bing may work: http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following logic works for me:

```
Document doc =
    Jsoup.connect(request)
         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
         .timeout(5000).get();

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {

    String temp = link.attr("href");
    if (temp.startsWith("/url?q=")) 
        result.add(temp);

}
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with some explanation of how it solves the problem.

Comment: hahah I only assume that is it impersonate googlebot and google captcha passes it trough xD

Answer (score -1):

You cannot bypass it, however you can use 3rd party services for CPATCHA recognition and post proper answer. Check [DeatchByCaptcha.com](http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login)

Answer (score -1):

The only way to solve this is display the captcha to user then save cookie from the response header.